# Ruby on Rails Active Record Interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new in `Ruby on Rails`, I'm wondering, is there a user interface to see all the data that you have in your `Active Record Models` and manipulate them just like `PhpMyAdmin`?

Comment: Sadly no - you have to write that interface... :)
If you're new to Rails, I can highly recommend reading your way through the Rails Guides here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ It will help you level up in all the fundamental aspects of Rails :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly no - you have to write that interface yourself... :)

There are ways to quickly scaffold up an interface for each of your models. Look at doco on `rails generate scaffold` for more info.

There are also gems that will automate some admin-scaffolding for you:
Look at eg `ActiveAdmin`

But in practice nobody keeps either of these around for long in their projects (for various reasons).

If you're new to Rails, I can highly recommend reading your way through the Rails Guides here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org It will help you level up in all the fundamental aspects of Rails :)

Answer (score 0):

There are gems in rails to maintain tables in rails app:

1. **ActiveAdmin**: It provides admin panel using which you can add/update/delete any record under tables.
2. **rails_db_info**: Just and it under Gemfile and run bundle install. Go to "/rails/info/db" link, it will list all tables with schema details. Its very easy to integrate.